# Keras / Tensorflow: Weird dropout behaviour

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I wanted to see how dropout works so I went into the layers.core
module and changed the dropout call from in_train_phase to
in_test_phase.

I'm not sure if my change is responsable for the weird dropout behaviour,
so please bear with me.

Now with these changes in mind the following code snippet:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dropout, Input
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import initializers

x=np.ones((2,2,4))
# x[:,1,:] = 1

print(x)

from keras.layers import Dense

input = Input(name='atom_inputs', shape=(2, 4))

x1 = Dense(4, activation='linear',
           kernel_initializer=initializers.Ones(),
           bias_initializer='zeros')(input)
x1 = Dropout(0.5, noise_shape=(tf.shape(input)[0], 1, 4))(x1)


fmodel = Model(input, x1)
fmodel.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
print(fmodel.predict(x))
```

will produce different predictions depending on the dropout rate.

e.g.:

```
Dropout(0.2)
[[[5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5.]]

 [[5. 0. 5. 0.]
  [5. 0. 5. 0.]]]

Dropout(0.5)
[[[0. 0. 8. 8.]
  [0. 0. 8. 8.]]

 [[8. 0. 8. 8.]
  [8. 0. 8. 8.]]]
```

Where am I going wrong? The dropout is defined on the dense output layer,
so it should only affect the neurons that turn off and on, but not their
respective values. Right?

Comment: What did you change exactly from layers.core? Surely that is the reason for the strange behavior. If you undo that change, and test with different droput rates, does the error persist?

Comment: keep experimenting with minimal changes and let us know.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Dropout in Keras is only active during training. So my (perhaps naive way) to make it visible was to change the -- I guess callback -- in the dropout class and use in_test_phase instead of in_train_phase, which causes this behaviour. If you know of any other way to check the dropout layer, pls clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because when using `Dropout`, you not only turn on and off different neurons but also scale data in order to compensate the fact that the following layer could receive less signal due to blacking out part of neurons. It's called an inverted dropout and you may read about it [here](https://pgaleone.eu/deep-learning/regularization/2017/01/10/anaysis-of-dropout/).

So basically each output from your network is rescaled by a `1 / (1 - p)` factor for this compensation. This is why your outputs differ.

For `Dropout(0.2)` compensation is `1 / (1 - 0.2) = 1.25` and this results in `5 = 4 * 1.25` and for `Dropout(0.5)` compensation is `1 / (1 - 0.5) = 2` and this results in `8 = 4 * 2`.

Comment: Interesting, so is this a feature that enables signals to still trigger the activation of its layer, compensating for "less" neurons firing due to Dropout?

Comment: Yes. Without that switching from training phase to inference phase could severely change networks behavior.